# gnome music player showing double tracks

Tags: gnome, music, mp3-tag

I have a question about gnome music player;
It shows double tracks in some albums (not all) while there is only one if I check it in nautilus.

All files are mp3 with ID3 tags edited using easytag. Maybe there is some glitch in the tag. Banshee does the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there might be a file with an extension .m3u in the folder, "playlist.m3u" or something of that sort.  In the past I've seen duplicate tracks in my playlist and after deleting the .m3u file the duplicates vanished